# await not efficient in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to parse pdf datas asynchronously, then populate a JS object with the content of the pdf file, and then return it in a Promise.
I am using the "pdfreader" module and its method parseFileItems()

```
async function parsePdfDatas(filePath){

  var output = {};
  var reader = new pdfreader.PdfReader();

  await reader.parseFileItems(filePath, function(err, item) {

    // item treatment populating output Object
  });

  return output;

}

parsePdfDatas("./****.pdf").then( function(output) {
  console.log(output);
});
```

The await statement doesn't work, anybody get an idea ?
EDIT
After xMayank answer, i tried as follows, which doesn't work neither:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var pdfreader = require("pdfreader");

var row = {
  id: "",
  muban: "",
  get mID() {
    this.id.slice(6,8);
  },
  tambon: "",
  get tID() {
    this.id.slice(4,6);
  },
  amphoe: "",
  get aID() {
    this.id.slice(2,4);
  },
  changwat: "",
  get cID() {
    this.id.slice(0,2);
  }
}

function parsePdfDatas(filePath){

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    var output = {};
    var reader = new pdfreader.PdfReader();

    reader.parseFileItems(filePath, function(err, item) {

        if(item && item.text && item.text.match(/^-{1,3}[0-9]{1,4}-{1,3}$/) === null && item.y != 2.887){

            if(item.x === 2.388){

                // If the row object contains a muban entry, we push it at the end of output
                if(row.id !== ""){

                    //console.log(row);
                    output[row.id] = {mName : row.muban, tName : row.tambon, aName : row.amphoe, cName : row.changwat};

                }

                // new line, row object reinitialization
                row.id = row.muban = row.tambon = row.amphoe = row.changwat = "";

            }

            // correction for ่ ้
            if(item.R[0].T === "%E0%B8%BD") item.text = "่";
            if(item.R[0].T === "%E0%B8%BE") item.text = "้";

            if(item.x >= 2.388 && item.x < 11.303)
                row.id += item.text;
            else if(item.x >= 11.303 && item.x < 17.969)
                row.muban += item.text;
            else if(item.x >= 17.969 && item.x < 23.782)
                row.tambon += item.text;
            else if(item.x >= 23.782 && item.x < 29.698)
                row.amphoe += item.text;
            else if(item.x >= 29.698)
                row.changwat += item.text;

            console.log(item.R[0].T + " -> " + item.text);
            //console.log(item.text + " : x = " + item.x + " | y = " + item.y);

        }
        
    });

    resolve(output);

  });

}

parsePdfDatas("./files/mubans0.pdf").then((output) => {
  console.log(output);
});
```

Comment: `await` waits for a promise to resolve ... `reader.parseFileItems` doesn't return a promise

Comment: does parseFileItems return a Promise?

Comment: https://github.com/adrienjoly/npm-pdfreader/blob/1a99120401bace50a6e7d55b0526641ba0c29ab5/PdfReader.js#L44

Comment: Placing the return statement inside parseFileItems's callbak and removing await should do.

Comment: @Ravi - no, since asynchrony inside the parseFileItems remains asynchronous

Comment: Looking at the code link posted, since the callback to `reader.parseFileItems` can be called more than once, you'll need to think of a different way to achieve what you want, since there's no obvious indication of when the call is complete - not even "bare" Promises will help

Comment: @JaromandaX Maybe a Promise could work if we use a for loop in the `reader.parseFileItems` parsing file by file and then resolve when every file is parsed.

Comment: so, change the code in `reader.parseFileItems` @DanielRodríguezMeza? Sounds messy

Answer (score 0):

Works fine.

```
const { PdfReader } = require("pdfreader");

function readFile(file){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    new PdfReader().parseFileItems(file, function(err, item) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else if (!item) resolve();
      else if (item.text) resolve(item.text);
    });
  })

}

readFile("./****.pdf")
  .then(result =>{
    console.log("Here", result)
  })
```

Comment: If you have multiple files this will only return the first parsed file

Comment: No this does work with multiple files. Function is resolving everytime.

Comment: you can't resolve a promise more than once ... but the callback can be called more than once (for each item it finds) ... is the callback called at the end with an empty item?

Comment: parseFileItems() parse each character of the pdf. I want to process each chars and return an object once parseFileItems is finished. I did edit my question to show you what I tried, which doesn't work.

Comment: xMayank - your answer works fine for the first character of the pdf only, and I am confused about how to organise those asynchronous functions combine with the loop of parseFileItems() method.

Comment: I did end making my own module (extending pdf2json) as  @JaromandaX suggested.

Comment: @escteban - I actually didn't suggest that :p I thought that would be messy